# Why is df.to_string printing out weird labels?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

If I run the code like so:

```
print(df['Col1'].to_string(index=False))
```

I get:

```
1
2
3
```

Now if I use the code like so (without print):

```
 s = df['Col1'].to_string(index=False)
 s
```

I get:

```
'1\n2\n3'
```

Where are the backslashes and 'n' strings coming from? What is the appropriate way of listing a single columns with an ultimate goal of assigning to an array?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert a data column to a list (array), then use this code:

`col_list = df['Col1'].values`

or

`col_list = list(df['Col1'])`

The `\n` sequence is a popular one found in many languages that support escape sequences. It is used to indicate a new line in a string. And `print` function will format the given string & inserts a new line